# How to combine two plots with the same y-axis

Tags: plotting, graphics

I have a data file which contains three columns of data. The first and the second column correspond to $x$ coordinates, while the third column to $y$ coordinate. Here is a small sample of the data file:

```
data = {{0.5, -77.06771909999159, 0.0012271846271586164},
        {1.0, 0.9928749927334053, 0.019634954034537862},
        {1.5, 78.49520253892854, 0.09940195479984795},
        {2.0, 173.19305308215831, 0.3141592645526058},
        {2.5, 289.4742561958002, 0.7669903919741358},
        {3.0, 428.890904029252, 1.5904312767975672},
        {3.5, 592.1255900024181, 2.9464702898078396}}
```

For the first plot we use

```
S01 = ListPlot[Flatten[List /@ data[[All, {1, 3}]], 1], 
 Joined -> False, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.01], Black}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x1", "M"}, 
 RotateLabel -> False, ImageSize -> 550]
```

which gives

[image: plot1]

and for the second plot

```
S02 = ListPlot[Flatten[List /@ data[[All, {2, 3}]], 1], 
 Joined -> False, PlotStyle -> {PointSize[0.01], Black}, 
 Axes -> False, Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x2", "M"}, 
 RotateLabel -> False, ImageSize -> 550]
```

[image: plot2]

Now, I want to combine these two plots keeping the same $y$ axis as it is, set the first $x$ axis (and of course the corresponding labels and tick marks) at the bottom of the frame and the second $x$ axis at the top of the frame. Is this doable? If so, any suggestions?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Why using `Flatten[List /@ data[[All, {1, 3}]], 1]` rather than just `data[[All, {1, 3}]]` ?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Just to make sure that there are no extra `{}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$x1$ and $x2$ are not linearly correlated so we have to find a transformation, I decided to use 3rd degree polynomial:

```
 sol[x_] = Normal @ NonlinearModelFit[data[[;; , {1, 2}]], 
                                      a x^3 + b x^2 + c x + d, {a, b, c, d}, x]

Plot[sol[x], {x, 0, 4}, Epilog -> Point@data[[;; , {1, 2}]], AxesLabel -> {"x1", "x2"},
                        BaseStyle -> {15, PointSize@.02}]
```

> $6.73694 x^3-3.34503 x^2+140.344 x-145.979$

[image]

Now we have to create ticks:

```
ticks = {x /. Solve[sol[x] == #, x, Reals][[1]],
         #} & /@ FindDivisions[{sol@0, sol@3.5}, 40];

ticks = MapIndexed[ If[Divisible[First@#2 - 1, 5], {##, {0.03, 0}} & @@ #, 
                                                   {First@#, ""}] &
                    , ticks, 1];

ListPlot[data[[;; , {1, 3}]], Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> PointSize@.02,
                              FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {All, ticks}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Not exactly like this. The `x2` axis should be calibrated so as the points to match. Now apart the first and the last point, all the others appear double.

Comment: Yes, I know that in the second plot x steps are not equal. However, there must be a way to regulate the step in such a way in order to fit with the x step of the first plot thus producing one dot only not two.

Comment: If I understand correctly the "one line", then yes.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z ok see my edit

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I wanted. Many thanks!